# nginx + varnish redirect server IP to url

Tags: redirect, nginx, varnish

i have nginx on port 8080 sitting behind varnish running on port 80. there is only one website on my server. the problem is you can access it by server's IP address too, instead of just url. google indexed this ip and i am afraid of problems with duplicate content.

how do i redirect requests going to IP address to my URL? i tried this code, but it ended up with loop redirects error.

```
server {
    listen 180.10.1.1:80;
    server_name 180.10.1.1;
    rewrite .* http://www.mysite.com$request_uri permanent;
}
```

thanks

edit:
rest of vcl

```
server {
    listen   8080;
    server_name  site.com;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;
    error_page 502  /502.html;

## Default location
    location / {
        root   /home/site.com/public_html;
        index  index.php;
...
```

Comment: Can you paste in the rest of your VCL?

Comment: Hi, did you paste the VCL or is that your nginx.conf ?

Comment: this is nginx.conf. there is nothing that could really have impact on this in VCL - only the server definition: `backend default {
  .host = "123.45.678.9";
  .port = "8080";
}`

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of ways to solve this. If Nginx is also serving site.com when you visit the server IP Address then you should adjust the Nginx config so any requests which are directed at the IP address redirect to site.com. Then restart both Nginx and Varnish.

Comment: i did that but like i wrote, it didnt work, ending up in redirect loops

Answer (score 1):

ok the problem was "180.10.1.1:" in the listen directive. i kept there only "listen 80" and now it works fine :)